# .NET MAUI ListView not rendering data

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to show the medicineList data in the ListPage.xaml using ListView. I have checked the documentation but I don't find anything noticeable. I have looked at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview) and tried to follow it. But it is not working.

This is ListPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using MedicineAlert.Data;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace MedicineAlert.Pages;

public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<MedicineData> MedicineList { get; set; }
    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Retrieve the app's local data directory path
        string localDataDirPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        // Combine the local data directory path with your desired subdirectory
        string dbFolderPath = Path.Combine(localDataDirPath, "DB");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(dbFolderPath, "data.json");

        if(File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            MedicineList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MedicineData>>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

This is ListPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MedicineAlert.Pages.ListPage"
             Title="ListPage"
             x:Name="MedicinesPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MedicineList, Source={x:Reference MedicinesPage}}"
        >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell
                        Text="{Binding MedicineName}"
                    />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is AppShell.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MedicineAlert.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MedicineAlert.Pages"
>
    <TabBar>
        <Tab
            Title="Add"
            Icon="add.png"
        >
            <ShellContent
                Title="Home"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AddPage}"
                Route="AddPage" 
            />
        </Tab>

        <Tab 
            Title="List"
            Icon="list.png"
        >
            <ShellContent
                Title="List"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ListPage}"
                Route="ListPage" 
            />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

The ListView in ListPage is not rendering. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `ListView` is not rendering is two-fold:

1. The `internal List<MedicineData> medicineList` is a field, but it should be a property as only properties can be used in binding expressions
2. Your `ItemsSource` binding is not pointing to the code-behind

First, change the field into a property:

```cs
public List<MedicineData> MedicineList { get; }
```

after that, move the `InitializeComponent();` call to the end of the constructor:

```cs
public ListPage()
{        
    // Retrieve the app's local data directory path
    string localDataDirPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    // Combine the local data directory path with your desired subdirectory
    string dbFolderPath = Path.Combine(localDataDirPath, "DB");
    string filePath = Path.Combine(dbFolderPath, "data.json");

    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        MedicineList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MedicineData>>(json);
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This is required, because in your case the binding will only get evaluated once and that happens during the `InitializeComponent();` call.

Finally, update the XAML as follows using a binding `Source` which points to the name of the page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MedicineAlert.Pages.ListPage"
             Title="ListPage"
             x:Name="MedicinesPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MedicineList, Source={x:Reference MedicinesPage}}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell
                        Text="{Binding MedicineName}"
                    />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Binding a page to its own code behind is also an option by setting `BindingContext = this;`, but that's not necessary with this approach.

***Note:** It's not recommended to load data inside a constructor. You may want to rethink your code design here. If you need to update the `List` frequently, you should replace it with an `ObservableCollection` and make the property itself also observable. This is a common use case for the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm).*

Comment: Updated my code. But still not working.

Comment: Does the JSON deserialization work? Are there actually any items in the `MedicineList`?

Comment: Yes, already checked that. There are 3 items in the MedicineList that I previously added.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. You should consider switching to the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm), it's more versatile and handles updates to properties much better. It also separates UI and business logic (such as loading the `MedicineData` objects from an API or database).

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

1. Try to replace the following code

```cs
internal List<MedicineData> medicineList;
```

with

```cs
public List<MedicineData> medicineList { get; set; }
```

2. Set the `BindingContext` for your page:

```cs
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    //internal List<MedicineData> medicineList;
    public List<MedicineData> medicineList { get; set; }

    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Retrieve the app's local data directory path
        string localDataDirPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        // Combine the local data directory path with your desired subdirectory
        string dbFolderPath = Path.Combine(localDataDirPath, "DB");
        string filePath = Path.Combine(dbFolderPath, "data.json");
    
        if(File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            medicineList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MedicineData>>(json);
        }

        // set BindingContext here
        this.BindingContext = this;    
    }
}
```

**Note:**

You can recheck if you have get the correct data for `medicineList`.